# Radio buttons quit working with rb class change

Tags: vb.net, radio-button

I have a group of radio buttons (3) that populates the correct one for each record based on the input of the Database.

The Data column it reads will have only one of three values: 'SLSC', 'SLDC', 'DLDC'.

Based on that, one radio button of the three options will be checked on the record. This worked fine until I changed the style of radio buttons being used. I changed from the default vb radio button to the SkinRadioButton class however I kept the original naming convention for each radio button.

During debug; I receive the proper response from the database, say for example the DB returns 'SLSC' as the value. In my SELECT CASE section it shows DvrResp = SLSC yet fails to see the true statement and no radio button is set to true (or ticked). It simple looks at the 3 cases and then executes the CASE ELSE and moves on. Would changing to SkinRadioButton seriously cause this piece of code to now not function as it once did? Is anyone able to advise why that would be and what I need to do to correct this please?

CODE:

```
    Private Sub LoadResp()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim reader As SqlDataReader

    Try
        cmd.Parameters.Clear()
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT DRIVER_COUNT 
                             FROM LOAD_INFO_TABLE 
                            WHERE PETS_LOAD_NUMBER = @dc"

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dc", tbPetsLoadNumber.Text)

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.Connection = New SqlConnection With {
            .ConnectionString = My.MySettings.Default.MY_DatabaseConnectionString
        }
        cmd.Connection.Open()

        Try
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            Dim DvrResp As String

            With reader
                .Read()

                DvrResp = .GetString(0)

                Select Case True
                    Case DvrResp = "SLSC"
                        rbSLSC.Checked = True
                        rbSLSC.BackColor = Color.Yellow
                        rbSLDC.BackColor = Color.Transparent
                        rbDLDC.BackColor = Color.Transparent

                    Case DvrResp = "SLDC"
                        rbSLDC.Checked = True
                        rbSLSC.BackColor = Color.Transparent
                        rbSLDC.BackColor = Color.Yellow
                        rbDLDC.BackColor = Color.Transparent

                    Case DvrResp = "DLDC"
                        rbDLDC.Checked = True
                        rbSLSC.BackColor = Color.Transparent
                        rbSLDC.BackColor = Color.Transparent
                        rbDLDC.BackColor = Color.Yellow
                    Case Else
                        Exit Select
                End Select

                Return

            End With

            reader.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
    cmd.Connection.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: I've had something similar when changing controls and keeping the name. To resolve, I removed all the controls, both from the gui and the designer file (if they were still present there), and then manually added them back again.

Comment: Well, to me if it's executing the Case Else it would suggest the value of DvrResp isn't what you're expecting.  Is it exactly the same including case and any white space?  What exactly is the value of DvrResp at the Select Case point in your code?

Comment: Problem was resolved. Hursey had the correct response in that there was an extra space added at the end of the DvrResp that was not being accounted for. That space has since been removed and it now works. Thanks.